# Why is this WiX Error Dialog causing error "next pointers do not form a single loop"

Tags: wix, installation, windows-installer

I currently have an Error Dialog (part of a library - ErrorDialog.wxs) referenced in my main Product.wxs file. I was not having any problems with my installer until I added a requirement for .NET 4 and tried run my installer on a VM that does not have .NET 4

```
<Condition Message= "You must install Microsoft .NET Framework 4.0 or higher.">
   <![CDATA[Installed OR NETFRAMEWORK40FULL]]>
</Condition>
```

Now when I hit this condition, instead of showing the error message as expected, I get "Error 2834:  The next pointers on the dialog **ErrorDialog** do not form a single loop"

I have included my ErrorDialog at the bottom. I am new to WiX and tried to follow what the documentation required for an error dialog. Any ideas why this is not working?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Fragment>
    <UI>
      <Property Id="ErrorDialog" Value="ErrorDialog"/>
      <Dialog Id="ErrorDialog" Width="370" Height="270" Title="[ProductName]" ErrorDialog="yes">

        <Control Id="ErrorText" Type="Text" X="4" Y="71" Width="341" Height="80" TabSkip="no"/>

        <Control Id="A" Type="PushButton" X="300" Y="240" Width="56" Height="17" TabSkip="yes" Text="Abort">
          <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="ErrorAbort">1</Publish>
        </Control>

        <Control Id="I" Type="PushButton" X="300" Y="240" Width="56" Height="17" TabSkip="yes" Text="Ignore">
          <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="ErrorIgnore">1</Publish>
        </Control>

        <Control Id="C" Type="PushButton" X="300" Y="240" Width="56" Height="17" TabSkip="yes" Text="Cancel">
          <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="ErrorCancel">1</Publish>
        </Control>

        <Control Id="N" Type="PushButton" X="300" Y="240" Width="56" Height="17" TabSkip="yes" Text="No">
          <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="ErrorNo">1</Publish>
        </Control>

        <Control Id="O" Type="PushButton" X="300" Y="240" Width="56" Height="17" TabSkip="yes" Text="OK">
          <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="ErrorOk">1</Publish>
        </Control>

        <Control Id="R" Type="PushButton" X="300" Y="240" Width="56" Height="17" TabSkip="yes" Text="Retry">
          <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="ErrorRetry">1</Publish>
        </Control>

        <Control Id="Y" Type="PushButton" X="300" Y="240" Width="56" Height="17" TabSkip="yes" Text="Yes">
          <Publish Event="EndDialog" Value="ErrorYes">1</Publish>
        </Control>

        <Control Id="Banner" Type="Bitmap" X="0" Y="0" Width="370" Height="44" TabSkip="no" Text="Banner" />
        <Control Id="Banner" Type="Line" X="0" Y="44" Width="370" Height="0" />
        <Control Id="Bottom" Type="Line" X="0" Y="234" Width="370" Height="0" />
        <Control Id="Title" Type="Text" X="15" Y="6" Width="340" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="An Error Occurred." />        
      </Dialog>
    </UI>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar error and I fixed it by removing the `TabSkip="no"` on all controls except the `ErrorText` control.